# System monitor in console mode

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, system-monitor

Is there a way to start system monitor app, from the console ??
 I am not talking about terminal.
I am talking about  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> mode

Comment: Plenty of command line options in [System Monitoring Tools For Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/293426/158442)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use `htop` also and its more featured than top .

if you want to test it , then you have install it with

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

after that type `htop` .

Comment: Depending on what your interested in, you might also want a specilized monitoring tool like iptraf, to monitor network traffic (very useful on a router)

Comment: For a lot more detail about `htop` you can look at this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/787642/system-monitor-doesnt-accurately-show-memory-usage/971157#971157

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `top` command to have a system monitor in console. It will display the CPU usage for the processes running in your machine.

Another alternative is conky-cli. You can install it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install conky-cli
```

or using the link [conky-cli](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/conky-cli) [image: Install conky-cli]

After installation, start it with `conky` command.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `dstat`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dstat
```

then run it by simply entering

```
dstat
```

to get this default output which updates every second and provides column headers with every screenful:

[image]

The advantage `dstat` has over `htop` is the same that `System-Monitor` has, namely that it shows trends.

---

`dstat` is very versatile.  Here is an article that explains the command line switches and shows some of the advanced options:

[5+ “dstat” Command Usage Examples in Linux](http://www.sanfoundry.com/5-dstat-command-usage-examples-in-linux/)

Comment: After writing this post I discovered that it works well to use Xming with PuTTY to get an X11 terminal over ssh - not on point of the question, but useful info even though the character terminal is much, much faster:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/971171/how-to-use-putty-to-get-x11-connections-over-ssh-from-windows-to-ubuntu/971172#971172

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like how dstat has few dependencies, shows trends, and combines all CPUs. I only wish the CPU history were graphical instead of numerical

Answer (score 1):

`nmon` from the eponymous package.

[image]

Comment: nmon is great! It shows historical trends for CPU usage, combines all CPUs into one chart, works on the console, and has light package dependencies.