# How to launch GUI interface on ubuntu 18.04 VM through putty from windows 10 machine

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, gui, .desktop

I am a new user of ubuntu. I get access to ubuntu server via a VM. I logged in to ubuntu VM through putty from windows 10 machine.

I installed the desktop on the server using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

My question is how do I launch the desktop environment through putty and how switch back to command line ?

It's very basic question but since I have just started using this environment, I hope it will not bother you and may be helpful for new bees like me.

**EDIT**
I followed the instructions from the linked post in the comment and installed the Xming. Done setting of the Putty according to instructions about XLaunch and run putty. But it doesn't open the GUI, rather command line.

Link to earlier post I followed:
[StackOverflow:  launch GUI interface on ubuntu 18.04 VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971171/how-to-use-putty-to-get-x11-connections-over-ssh-from-windows-to-ubuntu)

Here is log file of the Xming.

```
Welcome to the Xming X Server
Vendor: Colin Harrison
Release: 6.9.0.31
FreeType2: 2.3.4
Contact: http://sourceforge.net/forum/?group_id=156984

Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard 

XdmcpRegisterConnection: newAddress 130.xxx.xx.xxx
winCheckDisplayNumber - CreateMutex failed: Access is denied.

Fatal server error:
InitOutput - Duplicate invocation on display number: 0.  Exiting.

winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://askubuntu.com/questions/971171/how-to-use-putty-to-get-x11-connections-over-ssh-from-windows-to-ubuntu

Comment: I followed the instructions from the thread. Installed Xming, make settings in putty as described for Xlaunch and connect to Ubuntu VM from putty but it doesn't run GUI. Rather command line.

Comment: Here is log file of Xming:
Welcome to the Xming X Server
Vendor: Colin Harrison
Release: 6.9.0.31
FreeType2: 2.3.4
Contact: http://sourceforge.net/forum/?group_id=156984
Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard 
XdmcpRegisterConnection: newAddress 130.xxx.xx.xxx
winCheckDisplayNumber - CreateMutex failed: Access is denied.
Fatal server error:
InitOutput - Duplicate invocation on display number: 0.  Exiting.
winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress